# SOA suite with Remote DB server

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, soa, weblogic11g

I have the Oracle client, weblogic and the SOA suite 11g installed on a Win 7 machine. The Oracle DB is on a server 2008.

I have the hardest time connecting to it. The server name is S2008 on port 1521. I used the RCU to install the schema.

I am able to ping the server. Could someone please help me out in getting this connected? I have not done this configuration before.

Thank you.

Comment: This might be better put to http://serverfault.com/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a database concern, not WebLogic.

The simplest thing to do is to confirm you can telnet to port 1521 from the WebLogicmachine (telnet  1521).  If this cannot connect, it is either a firewall issue or the TNS listener is not running on port 1521.  Check to make sure that port 1521 is opened on the Database host and then try again.

Also, try connecting outside of WebLogic to remove a variable from the problem.  This would be easier/faster anyway.  Try using SQL developer to connect to the host/port where the database is running.  This will show you the ORA-????? error(s) for the connection attempts without having to go through the connection wizard in the weblogic console

Comment: Thank your Jeff, I haven't use telnet in forever. By using your advise I noticed none of the ports were open. Everything works fine now. Thank you!!